# UIViewController's viewDidAppear not being called after a modal close

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios-simulator, viewdidappear

A UIViewController (View A) invokes another view controller (View B) by invoking it as a modal control.

[self presentModalViewController:ViewB animated:TRUE];

And View B exists by invoking:

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

When this occurs everything looks right EXCEPT that View A's viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear does not get called (they are called during app init though). Weird thing is... i believe ive done this before, but im not sure what is going on now.

Is there anything obviously wrong that im doing?
Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***
I just now learned that this behavior only occurs with the UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl transition type. For all other transition types the parent view-controller gets its viewDidAppear message just fine.

So now what am i suppose to do!?!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989680/how-to-know-when-dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-is-initiated-and-also-when-it

Comment: Not quite. this is a specific question related to the UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl transition. The delegates aren't called for this specific transition type. All others work just fine. BUG maybe???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran in to the same problem.

I solved it by adding a delegate and a delegate method.

So when Controller A opens Controller B as a modal view controller with a page curl i set the instance of controller b's.delegate to be controller a.

In controller B i add this:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (delegate)
        [delegate didCloseInfoViewController];
}
```