# close modal callback

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view with a table on it, on every table cell I can add some data, so I put it in modal which actually is another view. In my modal I have this code

```
@IBAction func closeModal(_ sender: Any) {

        if let amountVal = amount.text {
            if let amountInt = Int16(amountVal) {
                let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                let activity = Activity(context: context)
                activity.created_at = Date() as NSDate
                activity.amount = amountInt

                countedObject?.addToActivities(activity)

                do {
                    try context.save()
                    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                } catch let error {
                    NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }


        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So I update core data entity and close modal, but after closing modal the first view was not updated so it does not reflect the changes I made until restart of the simulator. In my first view I have this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        populateCountObjects()
    }
```

This works for simple segues but not for modal, what should I use in this case?

Comment: Your issue is that 'populateCountObjects()' is not called?

Comment: not really, seems like viewDidAppear is not called after modal is closed

Comment: Can you please pass message to this view controller via weak delegate so that it call populate method.

Answer (score 1):

So I did it in another way, I added to ViewController this

```
static var sharedInstace : ViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        ViewController.sharedInstace = self
    }
```

and in the modal after dismiss method

```
ViewController.sharedInstace?.didCloseModal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Posible duplicate : [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818614/uiviewcontrollers-viewdidappear-not-being-called-after-a-modal-close)

You need to use a delegate with a dedicated method

```
protocol ModalDelegate {
    func didCloseModal();
}
```

In your modal controller class, create an instance of ModalDelegate protocol. And call '`delegate.didCloseModal()`' before dismiss

Then make your parent controller implement `ModalDelegate` protocol
and implement the function `didCloseModal` like `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `viewDidAppear` method isn't called again. Try to use `NsNotification` to notify your first VC if the context saved and redraw/refresh/reload...etc what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let the system do the work for you. In this case you get a notification when the context is saved.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contextDidSave(_:)), name: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: context)
}

func contextDidSave(_ notification: Notification) {
    populateCountObjects()
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, you can always go lower and get notified whenever an object is changed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contextObjectsDidChange(_:)), name: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: context)
}

func contextObjectsDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    populateCountObjects()
}
```